# Bootstrap collapse div content disappears

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, material-design

I'm trying to create a collapsable div that holds thumbnails for images. So far, everything works except that the div content (the thumbnails) flashes and disappears upon collapse and expand. The content is there, it just doesn't stay. If you're quick enough you can click the thumbnail as it flashes and it takes you to the image path. My div looks like this:

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
    <div id="images" class="accordion-body collapse">
        <a href="../images/1953.01.09.00.jpg" class="thumbnail">
            <img src="../images/1953.01.09.00.jpg">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my button:

```
<a class="btn accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#images">Images &raquo;</a>
```

You can look at my full code here: https://jsfiddle.net/krbylit/jttyq8jv/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to your CSS

```
.collapse.show {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

For some reason your bootstrap doesn't toggle this property correctly

Answer (score 0):

sometime the case might be some css changes the color of the text inside to white so simply applying the inline css might help :

```
    style="color : black; "
```